# Bootstrap horizontal navbar with buttons to scroll content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, bootstrap-5

In my website that uses bootstrap, I have a navbar with a lot of categories on my website and it's currently displaying things like this:
[navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqJmQ.png)
The horizontal scroll is nice, but I want my website to be more modern and instead of the default scroll, I'd really like it to have some buttons to scroll through items like this (horizontal scroll with buttons):
[navbar i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db0kW.png)
I've been trying to find something like this on the official bootstrap website with no luck. Can you please tell me if there's a way to do what I want with the use of boostrap and maybe some javascript?

Here's my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Annchan4 Tasty Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <!--bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="w-75 mx-auto">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg"> <!--isso eh um flex-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" aria-current="page" href="#">
                            Promos
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Cakes
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Cookies
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Brownies
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Ice-cream
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Fudges
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Savory Crackers
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Savory Cakes
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Savory Breads
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Savory Muffins
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Pizzas
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Lunch
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Dinner
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Fit
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Smoothies
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item me-2">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light btn btn-secondary" href="#">
                            Market
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here`s my css:

```
#navbarNav {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.btn-secondary
{
    color:white;
}
```